# Python[fastapi,frontend] - How to auth the frontend?

Tags: python, jwt, frontend, fastapi

first time building frontend app,

in backend i'm running fastapi ,
I prepare the all required functionalities for security using JWT ,
and it being tested for all existing endpoints (non are webpage).

Now i added a small app to frontend and i'd like to understand
how i should restrict the access to users with valid token .

JWT restrict all non frontend endpoint by:

```
current_user: User = Security(get_current_active_user, scopes=["user_read"])
```

now i added frontend:

```
@customers_router.get("/customers", tags=["home"])
async def home(request: Request ,limit: int = 10) :
    customers_cursor =  DB.customer.find()
    customers = await customers_cursor.to_list(length=limit)
    customers = list(map(fix_customer_id, customers))
    return templates.TemplateResponse("customer.html",{"request": request, "customers": customers})
```

I'm not sure for how it should work...
I understand user need the be authorize by token and if his token is valid then he he should be able to get to the webpage "/customers",
can some1 guide me what i missing ?

Answer (score -1):

To secure your FastAPI frontend with JWT authentication, you can use the Depends function from FastAPI to enforce the authentication and authorization checks. Here's an example of how you can modify your code.
(Assuming you have a function to get the current user from the token, similar to get_current_active_user, you can create a dependency that enforces JWT authentication:)

```
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from jose import JWTError, jwt

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="token")

def get_current_user(token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    credentials_exception = HTTPException(
        status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
        detail="Could not validate credentials",
        headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"},
     )
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, YOUR_SECRET_KEY, algorithms=. 
               [ALGORITHM])
        username: str = payload.get("sub")
        if username is None:
            raise credentials_exception
    except JWTError:
        raise credentials_exception
    return username
```

NOTE: Replace YOUR_SECRET_KEY and ALGORITHM with your actual secret key and algorithm.
Now, you can use this dependency in your endpoint to ensure that the user has a valid token:

```
@customers_router.get("/customers", tags=["home"])
async def home(request: Request, limit: int = 10, current_user: str = 
Depends(get_current_user)):
    customers_cursor = DB.customer.find()
    customers = await customers_cursor.to_list(length=limit)
    customers = list(map(fix_customer_id, customers))
    return templates.TemplateResponse("customer.html", {"request": 
 request, "customers": customers})
```

In this example, the current_user parameter is using the get_current_user dependency, which checks for a valid JWT token. If the token is not valid or missing, FastAPI will return a 401 Unauthorized response.

Make sure to include the token in the Authorization header of your requests when accessing the /customers endpoint. For example, the header should look like:

```
Authorization: Bearer your_token_here
```

Remember to handle the token on the frontend side as well, sending it with each request to the /customers endpoint. This ensures that the user is authenticated and authorized to access the resource.